# Get string instead of list in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a column `Name` of string data type. I want to get all the values except the last one and put it in a new column `FName`, which I could achieve

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['John A Sether', 'Robert D Junior', 'Jonny S Rab'], 
                        'Age':[32, 34, 36]})
df['FName'] = df['Name'].str.split(' ').str[0:-1]

              Name  Age        FName
0    John A Sether   32    [John, A]
1  Robert D Junior   34  [Robert, D]
2      Jonny S Rab   36   [Jonny, S]
```

But the new column `FName` looks like a list, which I don't want. I want it to be like: `John A`.

I tried convert the list to string, but it does not seems to be right.
Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `.str.rsplit`:

```
df['FName'] = df['Name'].str.rsplit(n=1).str[0]
```

Or you can use `.str.extract`:

```
df['FName'] = df['Name'].str.extract(r'(\S+\s?\S*)', expand=False)
```

Or, you can chain `.str.join` after `.str.split`:

```
df['FName'] = df['Name'].str.split().str[:-1].str.join(' ')
```

---

```
              Name  Age     FName
0    John A Sether   32    John A
1  Robert D Junior   34  Robert D
2      Jonny S Rab   36   Jonny S
```